# How can I prove that it is impossible to find a cheater in shamir secret sharing?

Tags: secret-sharing

Three participants Quadratic polynomial, one cheater. The Cheater discloses a false (x,y) pair I need to prove that any one of the truth-telling participants can't tell which of the others is the liar. I do realize that any pair of participants have a linear subspace of possible solutions since they don't know the secret they can't tell if it is a member of their subspace, but I don't think it is a proof just an intuition as to why this claim is true.

Comment: What's a "cheater"?

Comment: Hey, there are three participants each holds a secret pair (x,y) one of the participants disclose a false pair he is the "cheater". they try to reconstruct the secret and find out they have a false result. I need to prove that it is impossible the find the lying participant.

Comment: **Related: [How do you find a cheater in Shamir Secret Sharing?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1483/12164)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that having two of three pairs does not reveal *any* information about the secret (polynomial). Also see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) on Shamir's secret sharing: it provides you with a nice graphical answer to your question.